# Strange passage in Whiterun

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I sneaked around behind the house of the Battle-Born and found a random passage that said 'To'. I used the glitch to get out of Whiterun and where it usually says something like 'To Skyrim', it only says 'To'. I walked towards it and entered the loading screen, where I could hear sounds in the background, but the game froze. Is this a deleted part of Whiterun?

Comment: No, never knew that was there. I ment outside the walls of Whiterun.

Comment: Yes I can redo it. It's like a deleted entrance

Comment: Can you possibly provide us with a screenshot of where you found this entrance?

Comment: Is that the one that is outside of Whiterun at the mills!?!? I went there ages ago to a "To" and froze on the loading screen aswell! Atleast I'm not the only one. @Ben If Ninja_Snipa is talking about the same thing, I just plate glitched out the entrance, went left and down to where the mills are.

Answer (score 7):

**It's in all probability a mistake.**

Toggling collision using `tlc` in the in-game console, I checked the location you mentioned, and found the 'random passage':

[image: Screenshot of the location in-game]
<sup>View from underneath the city wall, facing the House of Clan Battle-Born in Whiterun, and showing the text 'To'. Mind that it's not connected to the water outlet.</sup>

Going 'through' it, I was also shown a black loading screen (with only the mist or smoke), with the sounds continuing in the background. So we need to look for answers elsewhere.

In the Construction Kit we can check what entity causes this behaviour:

[image: Screenshot of the mentioned place from within the Construction Set]
<sup>To the right we again can see the House of Clan Battle-Born in Whiterun. The red cylinder shape left of the middle is the entity responsible for the 'Activator' showing up in-game. The green cylinder, and yellow arcade/door in the centre, are part of the entity.</sup>

The entity is a Reference, with Reference Editor ID *000351EC*. 

It refers to a *Door* named "Passage", with the ID "AutoLoadDoorHiddenMinUse01" (an entity used 5 times in the vanilla base game <sup>*</sup>). 

It has no Teleport data, meaning it leads nowhere - which probably explains why it only shows the word 'To' in-game. Nor does it have any other references or scripts to give us a clue to its purpose. 

Its checked flags are 'Hidden', 'Automatic Door', and 'Minimal Use':

[image: Screenshot of Construction Kit showing the dialogue boxes of the entity]

According to [*creationkit.com*](https://www.creationkit.com/index.php?title=Door#Door_Dialog), the 'Hidden' flag should - not surprisingly - hide the Door in-game. 

'Automatic Door' means it acts like a portal, and requires no interaction. 

'Minimal Use' makes sure NPC's will try to navigate around it.

I couldn't find any mention of the Reference ID through Google, and a quick skimming of the Unofficial Skyrim Patch [changelog](https://www.afkmods.com/Unofficial%20Skyrim%20Legendary%20Edition%20Patch%20Version%20History.html) doesn't give any results either.

### My guess it has no purpose (anymore), and can very well be a left-over from development.

**It *could* also still have something to do with the Civil War changes that a playthrough can bring about (linked to Whiterun being under attack), but that's nothing more than a hunch.**

---

<sup>* For those wanting to gaze even deeper into this abyss: below this is the 'Use info' popup of *AutoLoadDoorHiddenMinUse01*. The other references have active 'Teleports'.
[image: Screenshot of 'AutoLoadDoorHiddenMinUse01' Use info]</sup>

Comment: Why the downvote?